# Distribute entity classes over multiple projects (EF Database First)

Tags: entity-framework, entity, dbcontext

I am using an Entity Framework database first approach. Is it possible to use an entity from another assembly in a DbContext?

I have a central database layer project containing the DbContext. It should reference entities from different projects/assemblies.

My idea was the following which does not work:

1. Create an *.edmx file in a central database project and use DbContext code generation to generate entity classes.
2. Move each entity class to their correct project. For example the `User` entity class will be moved to the "Authentication" class library.